# Represent a query string in JSON

Tags: javascript, json, query-string

I have this Javascript data:

```
[{id:123,type:"test"},{id:154,type:"another"}]
```

How would you transform that into something so that I can pass it as a HTTP post request?

```
menu[0][id] = 123
menu[0][type] = test
menu[1][id] = 154
menu[1][type] = another
```

I dont want to pass the actual JSON data, I want to clean it up and pass it as formatted HTTP paramaters.

**EDIT**

Was able to parse the object on the client side using something like this, maybe you guys would suggest something better before I sign this as "answered"?

```
this.serialize = function(elem) {
    var childs = elem.childElements();
    var str = "";
    for(var i=0, item; i<childs.length; i++) {
        item = childs[i];
        str += ((i)?"&":"")+"menu[" + i +"][id]=" + item.id.replace(/item_/,"");
        str += "&menu[" + i +"][type]=" + item.className;
        str += "&menu[" + i +"][section]=" + elem.id;
        str += "&menu[" + i +"][position]=" + i;
    }
    return str;
}
```

Comment: Are you looking for the syntax that the query parameters would have to take?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var data = [{id:123,type:"test"},{id:154,type:"another"}];
var params = new Array();
for(var x = 0; x < data.length; x++) {
    params.push("id=[" + x + "]=" + escape(data[x].id));
    params.push("type=[" + x + "]=" + escape(data[x].type));
}
alert(params.join("&")); // output: id=[0]=123&type=[0]=test&id=[1]=154&type=[1]=another
```

Is that what you want?

Comment: oh nice, thanks, similar to my solution, I'll mark you ask fixed.

Comment: Be careful, you shouldn't iterate javascript arrays using the for(x in obj).. I believe it breaks in IE, use the for(var i=0 ...);

Comment: Doesn't it only break if people messed with the prototype?

Comment: I know it breaks if the "prototype" library is loaded.

Comment: @LucaMatteis the internal properties are also iterated, this is also a problem if you have any shims on Object.prototype.  You can add Object.hasOwnProperty(instance) as a sanity check for either case.

Answer (score 0):

```
"?qsparam=" + escape("[{id:123,type:'test'},{id:154,type:'another'},...]")
```

Comment: You might have miss understood my question, anyhow that is wrong anyhow, I dont want to pass the actual JSON data, I want to clean it up and pass it as formatted HTTP paramaters.

Answer (score 0):

menu0.id=123&menu0.type=test&menu1.id=154&menu1.type=another

This is fairly easy to parse on the server, in that it's a regular format.

Answer (score 0):

I believe HTTP POST only accepts a flat key/value collection, not any arbitrary JavaScript data structure.

If you *can* flatten it (for example, like John Stauffer shows), and if you're posting to your own domain, you can use an `XMLHttpRequest` to post and pass the key/value collection, formatted like a query string, with the [.send(data)](http://www.w3.org/TR/XMLHttpRequest/#send) method.

If you don't want to implement it yourself most JavaScript libraries should have an implementation (e.g. [jQuery.post](http://docs.jquery.com/Ajax/jQuery.post)).